# How can I make a dropdown menu where the second dropdown options depend on the first selection?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I would like a dropdown menu Where the options in the first box are 'state' and 'province' and the second will populate based on the first selection (state -> USA states, province -> canada provinces)
Here is the code I have so far:

```
<form id="updateTreventLocation" action="
<table>

 <%=Url.Action("SavedTreventLocation","Prod")%>" method="post">
  <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="label">City:</td>
        <td class="content">
            <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="CityLocation" value="<%=EditTreventLocation.locationCity%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="label">Province/State:</td>
        <td class="content">
            <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="ProvinceLocation" value="<%=EditTreventLocation.locationProvince%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: My Cascading DDL Blog does this exactly. see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the following link should help you get started making a dynamically-updated second dropdown based on the first one.

[Populate one dropdown based on selection in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another)