# How to populate dependant dropdowns in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to populate **TWO dropdownlist**, based on selection of first dropdownlist the second dropdownlist will get populated.

**Example :**

Like i have two dropdownlist namely **1.ddlCountry** and **2.ddlState**

Now when country is selected then depending on the selected **Country** the **States** related with that Country will get populated in the State dropdownlist. I want to achieve this withour reloading the whole page in Asp.Net with coding language as C#.

How can i achieve the same?

`Dropdownlist` is fetching data from database by executing query.

Comment: Can you show us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far?

Comment: This is duplicate question and you also haven't searched for this problem. Find answer with this link of stackoverflow itself : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258839/populate-dropdown-list-based-on-another-dropdown-list

Comment: can you share your code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `AJAX toolkit CascadingDropDown` as told by `Naresh`.
   OR
2. use [ajax update panel](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/11/112405.aspx) and keep all `Dropdowns` in it. So the whole page will not load on changing dropdown value.

> You didnt give the code to further solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FillStateByCountry();
}
protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FillLocationByCountryandState();
}

private void FillStateByCountry()
{
    DataSet dstFillState;
    int CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString());
    dstFillState = Tbl_State.FillDDLState(CountryId);
    ddlState.DataSource = dstFillState;
    ddlState.DataTextField = "State";
    ddlState.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlState.DataBind();
}
```

similarly `FillLocationByCountryandState();`

Answer (score 0):

Add two dropdownlists to your form and name it as `cmbStates`, `cmbCities`

when you select state name from `cmbStates(dropwdownlist)`, `cmbCities(dropdownlist)` generates cities based on state name(cmbStates)

**by fetching data from database**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=pbs-server;database=p2p;user id=shekar;password=sekhar@1346");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select states from Country", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds, "Country");
        cmbStates.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cmbStates.SelectedValue = 0;
        con.Close();

    }

    private void cmbStates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=xxxx;database=xxxx;user id=xxxxr;password=xxxxxx");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select cities from States where cityname = 'cmbStates.SelectedItem.ToString()'", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds, "States");
        cmbCities.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cmbCities.SelectedValue = 0;
        con.Close();           

    }
```

**OR**

**manually adding items**

```
namespace DropDownlist
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmbStates.Items.Add("Andhra Pradesh");
            cmbStates.Items.Add("Tamilnadu");
            cmbStates.Items.Add("Karnataka");
            cmbStates.SelectedValue = 0;
        }

        private void cmbStates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cmbStates.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Andhra Pradesh")
            {
                cmbCities.Items.Clear();
                cmbCities.Items.Add("Hyderabad");
                cmbCities.Items.Add("Guntur");
                cmbCities.Items.Add("Vijayawada");
                cmbCities.SelectedValue = 0;

            }
            else if (cmbStates.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Tamilnadu")
            {
                cmbCities.Items.Clear();
                cmbCities.Items.Add("Chennai");
                cmbCities.Items.Add("Coimbatore");
                cmbCities.Items.Add("ooty");
                cmbCities.SelectedValue = 0;

            }
            else if (cmbStates.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Karnataka")
            {
                cmbCities.Items.Clear();
                cmbCities.Items.Add("Bangalore");
                cmbCities.Items.Add("Mangalore");
                cmbCities.SelectedValue = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select any value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```