# How to create a dynamic dropdownlist in C# using OleDb connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, oledbconnection, dropdownlistfor

I would like to create a 2 dynamic dropdownlists, exactly the same as the project in the video below where both dropdownlists change according to the selection in the other dropdownlist. Only difference is, I would like to use OleDb connection as my database is in  Microsoft Access and I'm using visual studio to work on this project.

(Reference)

[ASP Net with C# Dynamic Dropdownlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hI0y-NZq8wQ&list=PLByDPHHnDS0XC3uTLVOKPxWhVne_qbde-&index=16)

Codes at:

- 14:13
- 24:28

How do I go about writing the code for this in C#?

My 2 drop down lists are - Models , Tester

Thanks.

Comment: In the video look at 6:50 , just need to select "Access Database".. rest should remain same.

Comment: If I'm not wrong the user did that to show an example of how to databind  and directly databinding to the drop down list was one of the examples. I do not intend to databind like that as I want my dropdownlist to change depending on what the user selects in the other dropdpwnlist and not show all the data.

Comment: Try this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258839/populate-dropdown-list-based-on-another-dropdown-list

Comment: Also this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL2F6Dvxy3I&ab_channel=.NETInterviewPreparationvideos