# JQuery to change value based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 dropdownlist, i want if i select Alabama in dropdwon1 the selected value in dropdwon2 should change in to Other.., how to do this using JQuery

```
<select id="dropdwon1">
<option value="1">Alabama</option>
<option value="2">Alaska</option>
<option value="3">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

---

```
<select id="dropdwon2">
<option value="3">Item1</option>
<option value="4">Item2</option>
<option value="5">Other..</option>
</select>
```

Comment: welcome to SO. you will get a lot more help if you show us what you have already tried. folks are willing to help but not until you have shown some effort on your part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate Dropdown list based on another dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258839/populate-dropdown-list-based-on-another-dropdown-list)

Comment: check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

You must bind event to first select change event and check it's selected value and set value for second select like this:

```
//Bind change event to first select
$('#dropdwon1').on('change', function(){

    //check selected value
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 1){

         //Set selected value for second select
         $('#dropdwon2').val(5);
    }
})
```

Comment: i have list of States in my dropdwon1 and in dropdwon2 list of County,,what i need is when i select any state other than Alabama in dropdwon1 the selected value in dropdwon2 should be other..

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your value for the second select for the **first value of your state select**, like so :

```
if($("#dropdown1").val()=="1"){
    $("#dropdown2").val("5"); // Set the value (your answer)
}
```

then use the `change` event and give the different values of the second select for the states values.

As the user can select Alabama again after having chosen another value, you have to put the code for the first value in the `change` event function.

Here is a jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/mantisse_fr/ak81o26s/4/

Comment: this what i need(if dropdwon1 value not Alabama then change dropdwon2 to Other.....)