# How to invoke Play framework Action from OnChange

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I am `newbie` to `Play Framework with Scala` environment.I would like to invoke `Controller` `Action` method from   `@select()`~`dropdown OnChange`.

**How I invoke from Button**

```
<a href="@routes.Application.cancel()"><span>Cancel</span></a>
```

**What I actually need**

I need to invoke my `Action` from drop down `OnChange` method.please help me to accomplish this task.

**Edit**

```
@select(
   userMapForm("department"),
   DepartmentList,//set values from DB
   '_default -> "-- Select Department --",
    'onChange->"//invoke Action from here"
                        )
```

Comment: Please show us some code! In general you'd do it like you used the route `@routes.Application.cancel()` in your link/button.

Comment: I need to invoke `Action` for example `@routes.Application.cancel()` in Drop down `OnChange` like how we invoked that action from `<a>` tag

Comment: @Kris I edited my code please have a check on it.

Comment: It looks like there is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552218/using-the-playframework-scala-select-template-onchange-event. Does it help?

Comment: No It doesn't have the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to do this with trivial javascript.

```
@select(
   userMapForm("department"),
   DepartmentList,//set values from DB
   '_default -> "-- Select Department --")


<script>
  document.getElementById("department").addEventListener("change", funciton(){
    location.replace("@routes.Application.cancel()");
  });
</script>
```

You could use jQuery to simplify it (or other javascript framework)

Comment: Thanks dude,it is working fine.I just modified it with below code 
`@select(   
 'onChange->"methodForTest()")

function methodForTest(){
location.replace("@routes.Application.cancel()");
};`