# Id value from combo box load and display into second combo box (Javascript PHP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

First combo box

```
                  <select name="no_kk" style="width: 68%;" class="select2" id="no_kk" onchange="get_Nokk(this.value);" >
                    <option value="">-- Pilih Nomor KK --</option>
                    <?php $kk = get_no_kk();
                      foreach ($kk as $key => $value) {?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $value->no_kk;?>"><?php echo $value->no_kk;?></option>
                    <?php
                      }
                    ?>
                    </option>
                  </select>
```

Second Combo box

```
                  <select name="propinsi" id="propinsi" style="width: 100%;" class="select2" onchange="get_cities(this.value);" >
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($prov);$i++){ ?>
                    <?php if($prov[$i]->is_removed != 1){ ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $prov[$i]->provinces_code;?>"><?php echo $prov[$i]->provinces_name;?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </select>
```

Javascript

```
  function get_Nokk(id)
  {
    if(id != null)
    {
      $.ajax({
        //url: "<?php echo site_url('mustahik/get_kk');?>",
        url: realUrl() + 'mustahik/get_kk',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.status_code == '000') {
              $('form[name="form_survey_kel"]').resetForm();
              for(var j=0;j<json.data.length;j++) {
                $("#nomor_kk").val(json.data[j].no_kk);
                $("#nama_kepala").val(json.data[j].name);
                $("#add_nokk").val(json.data[j].no_kk);
                $("#id_mustahik").val(json.data[j].id_mustahik);
                $("#id_keluarga").val(json.data[j].id_keluarga);
                $("#alamat").val(json.data[j].address);
                $("#propinsi").val(json.data[j].provinces_code);
                $("#kabupaten").val(json.data[j].cities_code);
                $("#kecamatan").val(json.data[j].districts_code);
                //$('option:selected').val();
                //cbGetProp();
              }});}
```

i want to ask .. about this .. i want to get data id in first combo box.. and load into second combo box ..

i use javascript like that, just get the value id but not display in combo box..

May you know to solve it ?.. Thank you

Comment: cek post ini bro, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another

Comment: oke bro .. meluncur